# Dynamic start date and endate for bootsrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootsrap datepicker for one of my project
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org
I used startDate and endDate option to enable dates in selected intervals.it is working fine if there is only 1 date range..but i want to use it inside ajax call,where startDate and endDate are received as response..if there is only one date range it is fine.if there is multiple date range only last date range is visible in calender.

Below is my code

```
success: function(res) {
    jQuery.each(res, function(index, value) {
        var i=0;
        var startDate = value[i+1], // some start date
        endDate  = value[i+2];  // some end date
        jQuery('#booking_page #ajax_date').datepicker({
            format: "yy-mm-dd",
            startDate: startDate,
            endDate: endDate
        });
    }); 
}
```

I want to show all these date range in same calender. How can I do it?

Comment: @Srinu using bootstrap datepicker..i want it on same calender..only one calender will be there

Comment: @Srinu thanks for reply..i passed it using yy-mm-dd..i dont think its format issue..dates are enabled for last executed loop..but then date range before that is gone that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one date range for any particular datepicker control.There cannot be multiple range in a single datepicker. Please be more specific about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks for replay..if i have 2 dates eg:- 5-10-2015 to 10-10-2015 and 25-10-2015 to 30-10-2015...can i enable dates between these 2dates in same calender..all other dates disabled..sory for my language..that is what i am trying to do..any way for it